# jQuery Restricting Special Characters and Limiting Number of Fields

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to restrict special characters for all input fields (except email ) and also restricts the number of characters allowed by ID.

So for example, an input field with the ID "middleinitial" would only allow one character and that character has to be alphanumeric, where the field with the ID "firstname" allows up to 50 characters and has to be alpha and the field ID "zip" has to be numeric and only allows 5 characters.

I found the jQuery Alphanumeric plugin which is no longer supported and Trey Hunner's replacement on stackoverflow (I'm aware of the other posts), but I'm not finding enough documentation to implement since I'm a novice to jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ is the go to plugin for form field validation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I  decided to hard code the "maxlength"in the HTML and use Trey Hunner's update to the alphanumeric jQuery plugin. I had to hunt down some documentation, so I've added a jsfiddle to help someone who happens across this with the same issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/QX76h/3/

http://treyhunner.com/2010/10/replacement-for-jquery-alphanumeric-plugin/

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.alphanumeric = function(r) {
        alphanumericHelper(this, r, true, true);
    };
    jQuery.fn.numeric = function(r) {
        alphanumericHelper(this, r, false, true);
    };
    jQuery.fn.alpha = function(r) {
        alphanumericHelper(this, r, true, false);
    };
    var alphanumericHelper = function(obj, restraints, alpha, numeric) {
        var regex = "";
        if (numeric)
            regex += "0-9";
        if (alpha) {
            if (restraints == undefined || !restraints.allcaps)
                regex += "a-z";
            if (restraints == undefined || !restraints.nocaps)
                regex += "A-Z";
        }
        if (restraints != undefined && restraints.allow != undefined)
            regex += RegExp.escape(restraints.allow);

        $(obj).regexRestrict(RegExp("[^"+regex+"]", "g"))
    };
})(jQuery);

/*
 * Function created by Colin Snover in response to an article by Simon Willison
 * on Regular Expression escaping in JavaScript:
 * http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/
 */
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

/*
 * Every time the form field is changed, sanitize its contents with the given
 * function to only allow input of a certain form.
 */
(function ($) {
    var inputEvents = "input";
    if (!("oninput" in document || "oninput" in $("<input>")[0])) {
        inputEvents += " keypress keyup";
    }

    jQuery.fn.restrict = function(sanitizationFunc) {
        $(this).bind(inputEvents, function(e) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var sanitizedVal = sanitizationFunc(val);
            if (val != sanitizedVal) {
                $(this).val(sanitizedVal);
            }
        });
    };

    /*
     * Every time the form field is changed, modify its contents by eliminating
     * matches for the given regular expression within the field.
     */
    jQuery.fn.regexRestrict = function(regex){
        var sanitize = function(text) {
            return text.replace(regex, '');
        };
        $(this).restrict(sanitize);
    }
})(jQuery);
```